# According to Catholic scholars, what did Jesus really mean by `eagles gathering around corpses'in Lk 17: 34-37?

Tags: catholicism, tradition, gospel-of-luke, judgement

We see Jesus showing a fore-frame of His Second Coming, in Lk 17: 34-37 (NRSVCE):

> I tell you, on that night there will be two in one bed; one will be taken and the other left.   There will be two women grinding meal together; one will be taken and the other left.” Then they asked him, “Where, Lord?” He said to them, “Where the corpse is, there the eagles will gather.”

Here, the disciples seem to be asking Jesus as to where the `taken ones'would be taken. But Jesus is answering as if the question was as to where the left ones would remain. Or, did he mean that the` taken ones' would fall dead and the `left ones' would continue living, the latter  not bothering to  bury their beloved dead  ones ? But then, why did Jesus ignore the Jewish tradition of   giving a decent burial to their dead ?  May be, he is referring to something else when he speaks of eagles gathering around corpses .  My question therefore, is: According to Catholic scholars, what did Jesus really mean by`  eagles gathering around corpses'in Lk 17: 34-37 ?

Comment: You don’t seem to be citing the NRSVCE since that doesn’t say “eagles” to my knowledge (please verify the correct citation). Here and in Matthew 24, ἀετοὶ is translated as “eagles” in the translation you’ve cited, whereas many modern translations use “vultures.” There may be a lack of precision when referring to birds, or this may be a reference to the Roman standard and thus prophetically referring to the destruction of Jerusalem. I once asked about this at https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/13/423 but the answers only address the former position, not the latter.

Comment: David B. Currie writes about the Olivet Discourse extensively from a Catholic perspective in *Rapture: The End-Times Error That Leaves the Bible Behind*

Comment: If you read the previous verses (26-32) you will see that the "taken ones" are taken in judgement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rheims version, following St. Jerome's Vulgate, says:

> [Lk. 17:37](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=49&ch=17&l=37-#x)  Wheresoever the body ([σώμα](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=greek&l=%CF%83%CF%8E%CE%BC%CE%B1#lexicon), *corpus*) shall be, thither will the eagles (αετοί, *aquilæ*) also be gathered together.

> [Mt. 24:28](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=24&l=28-#x)  Wheresoever the body ([πτώμα](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=greek&l=%CF%80%CF%84%CF%8E%CE%BC%CE%B1#lexicon), *corpus*) shall be, there shall the eagles (αετοί, *aquilæ*) also be gathered together.

A dead body is a πτῶμα, whereas a living body is a σώμα; St. Jerome uses *corpus* to translate both.

MacEvilly, [*An Exposition of the Gospels of Matthew & Mark* (4th ed.)](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=8433):

> 28. The words of this verse are supposed by many to be allusive to the passage of ([Job 39:30](https://isidore.co/aquinas/SSJob.htm#39)), where, treating of the eagle, God says, “*wheresoever the carcass shall be, she is immediately there*.” By some the words are supposed to be a Hebrew proverb, conveying, that no very great exertion or labour is needed for uniting those that are naturally united, and have a natural and irresistible tendency towards each other. He compares Himself to the carcass (the Greek for body is, πτωμα, a dead body), on account of His death, endured for our sakes, to procure glory for us, like that of His own glorified body. He compares His elect to “*eagles*,” because, as the eagle, this noble and royal bird, harmlessly escapes the lightning, so shall the elect escape unhurt, and stand in great constancy amidst the woes and lightnings of the last day. Moreover, as the eagles scent from an incredible distance, a dead body, and are carried aloft through space in quest of it, so, shall the elect be borne aloft in the air to meet Christ ([1 Thess. 4:16](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=59&ch=4&l=16-#x)), the great centre of attraction. To this St. Luke alludes ([17:36](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=49&ch=17&l=37-#x)).
>     The words of this verse would seem to be an answer to an implied complaint which might arise in the minds of His Apostles, viz., if Thy reign be thus brilliant, heavenly and passing, like the lightning, how can we enjoy it? He says, that His elect shall be permanently gathered to Him, so as to remain with Him, to enjoy Him. As the eagle, which is instinctively attracted to a carcass, floats aloft in air, crossing seas to enjoy it; so, shall they, after the resurrection from the tomb, renovated in youth like the eagle, be drawn to Him to enjoy Him, to feast with Him, and continue with Him for ever. The words, according to the Greek, ὅπου γαρ το πτωμα, &c., “*for, where the body is*,” &c., may be also regarded as illustrative, in a certain sense, of the preceding. They are a proverbial form of expression, showing, that a thing cannot be concealed. For, as the eagles scent their prey from afar, and make towards it; so, My glorious coming into the world shall not be hidden, but known to all. Wherefore, the faithful, like eagles of acutest sense, shall perceive My Divine presence, shall be attracted towards Me, and refreshed by My glory for ever. Hence, then, there shall be no need to inquire where is Christ; since, His coming shall be conspicuous and known to the entire world. Our Lord compares His *elect* to “*eagles;*” because, the *reprobate* shall not be borne aloft to meet the Judge, nor attracted to Him. They shall be reluctantly forced to appear at judgment.
>     St. Hilary infers from this verse, that our Redeemer will judge mankind in the place where His sacred body was raised on the cross, buried, and rose again. Thither shall all mankind proceed to be judged, near Jerusalem, in the valley of Josaphat, as the Prophet Joel teaches ([Joel 3:2](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=34&ch=3&l=2-#x)).

Comment: MacEvilly and St. Hillary appear to be at odds.  The former speaks of rescue and the latter of judgement.  I agree with Hillary.  By the preceding verses the "taken ones" are taken in judgement.